# How to define a typed props in nextjs with typescript?

Tags: typescript, next.js

First time typescript project and I need help on some basics...

It runs fine in npm run dev but I got an error when npm run build.

```
Type error: Binding element 'allImageData' implicitly has an 'any' type.
export default function Home({ allImageData }) {
                               ^
```

Code:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
const allImageData: { id: string; fullpath: string }[] = getAllImages();
    return {
     props: {
       allImageData,
    },
  };
}
export default function Home({ allImageData }) {
  ...
}
```

Question, how to make props typed?

Comment: Please, read the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

to answer my own question, just add any be done with it...

```
export default function Home({ allImageData }: any) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Nextjs has built-in type infer for server side processes. You can refer to [this part of nextjs document.](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-props#getstaticprops-with-typescript)